# How to export winrar profiles to another computer?

Tags: winrar

In Winrar, it is possible to save a collection of specific archiving settings into a "[profile](https://documentation.help/WinRAR/HELPProfiles.htm)" for reuse.

[image: like in the picture].

The problem:

1. It is not possible to edit the profile settings, only its name, as
   shown [here](https://documentation.help/WinRAR/HELPProfiles.htm): "You can not change compression options stored in a
   profile, but it is possible to change profile parameters, for
   example, its name or default status".
2. I want to transfer to another computer / send someone the profile I created. Seemingly there is no way to do that.

Does anyone know a way to export and import a profile to WinRar? These settings are saved somewhere, and there must be a way to do it.

From the software interface, and from their documentation, I assume the functionality does not exist.
I therefore ask, is it possible to extract this data in order to export it in another way. For example maybe they are kept in a Registry. Or other internal files.

Answer (score 1):

### 1. Editing an existing *WinRAR* profile

There can be modified all properties of a *WinRAR* profile by using the following steps:

1. Start *WinRAR*.
2. Press <kbd>Alt+A</kbd> or click on first item **Add** on the toolbar or click in second menu **Commands** on first menu item **Add files to archive**.
3. Click on first tab **General** on the button **Profiles** and click next in the opened menu on the menu item **Organize profiles...**
4. Select the profile to edit on left side of the dialog window **Organize profiles** and click on button **Edit**.
5. There can be edited some profile properties in the dialog window **Profile parameters**, but not the compression properties. That does not matter. Just make sure that the parameter *Immediate execution* is not checked in this dialog window. Then close the dialog window **Profile parameters** with button **OK** on having edited something or with button **Cancel** on not having changed anything in that window.
6. Click on button **Close** of dialog window **Organize profiles** and there is again displayed the dialog window **Archive name and parameters**.
7. Click once again on first tab **General** on button **Profiles** and this time click in opened menu on the profile of which compression properties should be modified.
8. The compression properties of the profile are loaded now and can be modified with clicking through the tabs of the dialog window **Archive name and parameters** and using the buttons on the tabs to open additional dialog windows with even more options.
9. When finished with the configuration of the compression options to use, select again the tab **General**, click once more on button **Profile** and click this time in the opened pop-up menu on first item **Save current settings to a new profile...**
10. Instead of entering a new profile name, select the profile which was loaded before from the profiles list. Then configure the other profile parameters below the *Profile name* list item as wanted and click on button **OK**.

The existing profile is overwritten with the compression options and profile parameters defined now which means the existing profile is edited.

### 2. Exporting and importing the *WinRAR* profiles

The *WinRAR* settings and profiles are nearly all stored in Windows registry under key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\WinRAR
```

There are three methods to export just the *WinRAR* profiles on one Windows PC and import them on another Windows computer.

#### 2.1 Exporting just the *WinRAR* profiles with Windows command `reg.exe`

There can be executed in a Windows **command prompt** window:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe EXPORT HKCU\Software\WinRAR\Profiles "%UserProfile%\WinRAR_Profiles.reg"
```

That command line exports just the `Profiles` key with all the subkeys and values to the Windows registry file `WinRAR_Profiles.reg` in the user's profile directory.

#### 2.2 Using the settings export feature of *WinRAR*

There can be opened in started *WinRAR* in last but one menu **Options** via second item **Import and export** the submenu with second item **Export settings to file**. A click on this menu item opens a dialog window to export the Windows registry keys and values of *WinRAR* into a Windows registry file of the user's choice.

It is advisable to first replace suggested `Settings.reg` by `%UserProfile%` and hit key <kbd>ENTER</kbd> or <kbd>RETURN</kbd> to change the directory to the user's profile directory.

There is by default suggested the file name `Settings.reg` which should be modified to `WinRAR_Settings.reg`.

A click on button **Save** finishes the export.

#### 2.3 Exporting the user's *WinRAR* settings with Windows command `reg.exe`

Another method to export most of the *WinRAR* settings is executing in a Windows command prompt window:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe EXPORT HKCU\Software\WinRAR "%UserProfile%\WinRAR_Settings.reg"
```

There is a difference between the registry file created by *WinRAR* on using **Export settings to file** and the file `WinRAR_Settings.reg` created with the command line above in the user's profile directory. The registry file created by *WinRAR* contains additionally the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\WinRAR` with all its subkeys and values.

#### 2.4 Removing settings data not to import on other PC

The Unicode encoded (UTF-16 LE with BOM) Windows registry file created by *WinRAR* or using the command line above with key `HKCU\Software\WinRAR` can be opened for editing with *Windows Notepad* by right clicking on file `%UserProfile%\WinRAR_Settings.reg` and clicking in opened context menu on menu item **Edit**.

The first line `Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00` must be kept as is. But the other lines can be deleted or modified to whatever should be imported later on the other computer.

It is necessary to delete all lines from the third line to the empty line above the line with `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\WinRAR\Profiles]` and all lines from `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\WinRAR\Setup]` to end of the file for copying just the *WinRAR* profiles to another computer and not the other settings. So the Windows registry file contains finally only the first line `Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00`, an empty line as second line and the lines of the key `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\WinRAR\Profiles]` with all the subkeys `0` to **n** depending on number of defined *WinRAR* profiles.

The modified registry file should be saved using the command **Save as** to `%UserProfile%\WinRAR_Profiles.reg`.

#### 2.5 Importing the *WinRAR* profiles on another Windows machine

The Windows registry file `%UserProfile%\WinRAR_Profiles.reg` created with one of the three methods described above and containing only the data of the key `Profiles` must be copied next to the other machine to directory `%UserProfile%`.

Then the import of the *WinRAR* profiles can be done by running following two commands in a command prompt window:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe DELETE HKCU\Software\WinRAR\Profiles /f
%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe IMPORT "%UserProfile%\WinRAR_Profiles.reg"
```

The first command line deletes the existing key `HKCU\Software\WinRAR\Profiles` with all subkeys and values.

The second command line imports the *WinRAR* profiles as stored in the registry file.

The deletion of the existing key `HKCU\Software\WinRAR\Profiles` is important as otherwise the result would be a mixture of *WinRAR* profiles as stored already in Windows registry for current user on the other PC and the profiles as stored in the  imported Windows registry file.

The used registry files can be deleted finally from both computers.

It is of course also possible to export and import just one of the defined profiles. There must be find out in this case only the profile number by looking on the lines in the Windows registry file containing the profile to export and import to another computer. Then only the lines of this profile should be kept in the Windows registry file. On the other PC must be first checked how many profiles are stored on this machine in the Windows registry of the current user and the profile number must be adapted accordingly in the Windows registry file before importing it.

Answer (score 0):

For those looking to transfer, export, or backup passwords, the specific reg key is `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\WinRAR\Passwords` - The one problem I still have is finding a way to combine multiple entries into one.

For example, I have an old drive where I saved passwords in WinRAR, and I formatted the drive since I didn't know about these methods here.  I was able to use software to recover the `NTUSER.DAT` and I could then it, by *Loading Hive* to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`

So now I have multiple `*\Passwords` registry entries, but I can't find a way to combine them.  I've tried exporting both, copying and pasting them together, and then importing, but it loses all the passwords.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?  It would be even better if there were a way to extract the data from the key. -- I wrote to support and received the following information about the encryption, but it is above my head.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1144017)